# canvas draw shape on MouseMove lag

Tags: wpf

I have very simple scenario: there is a canvas and I need to draw a line on canvas using MouseMove. But when I move the mouse pointer, second line's point (which is set in mouse move) doesn't match current mouse position.

**UPD 2:**
<s>Delta depends on speed of mouse, if speed is large - delta is large and noticeable(lag).</s> I've noticed that this bug is more visible if you move your mouse not very fast and not very slow.

You can download sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8N06JxC_Hl-NExTWUtTOFBBSnc/view?usp=sharing).

Something like on the picture when mouse moves fast:

[image]

Some source code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication32.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350">
<Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas"
        MouseLeftButtonDown="MainCanvas_OnMouseLeftButtonDown"
        MouseMove="MainCanvas_OnMouseMove"
        Background="White"
        />
```

```
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;

    namespace WpfApplication32
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            private Line _currentLine;
            private bool _isDrawing;

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
            }

            private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
            {
                MainCanvas.Focus();
            }

            private void MainCanvas_OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                if (_isDrawing)
                {
                    _currentLine = null;
                    _isDrawing = false;
                    return;
                }

                _isDrawing = true;

                _currentLine = new Line(){Stroke = Brushes.Green};

                var p = e.GetPosition(MainCanvas);

                _currentLine.X1 = p.X;
                _currentLine.Y1 = p.Y;
                _currentLine.X2 = p.X;
                _currentLine.Y2 = p.Y;
                MainCanvas.Children.Add(_currentLine);
            }

            private void MainCanvas_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                if (_currentLine == null)
                    return;

                var p = e.GetPosition(MainCanvas);
                _currentLine.X2 = p.X;
                _currentLine.Y2 = p.Y;
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried to use CompositeTarget.Render, also timer to change second point every 20ms but it didn't help.

I have legacy project in which code depends a lot on this approach(canvas mouseMove and shapes). So I need easiest way to eliminate this lag or some ideas about a reason of this bug) Thanks.

**UPD:**
I've tried to record video with this problem but I'm not good at it. Here is some screen from my recorded to show the problem:
http://prntscr.com/64hueg

**UPD 2:**
I've tried to use OnRender of Window object to do the same without canvas. I've used DataContext to draw the line - same issue here. DataContext is considered faster than Canvas and Line (Shape). So this is not Canvas issue.

I've also tried to use WritableBitmap to draw the line - no difference.

I thought that there might be a problem with MouseMove event - I read if there is a lot of objects(not my case but still) MouseMove might fire with delays so I used Win32 WM_MOUSEMOVE but it didn't helped as well. In my case delay between MW_MOUSEMOVE and wpf MouseMove event was <1000 ticks.

The only answer I see so far is render delay. I don't know how to improve it because it is wpf internals =(.
By the way Paint.net seems to use wpf and this problem occurs there as well.

Comment: Hi, I ve tried your source and it works perfectly, i don't see any offset between the line edge and the current mouse position !!...what dot net you are using ?

Comment: Hi @joseph, I'm using .net 4.0. My CPU is i3570k and I use hd4000 integrated video card. But this problem doesn't occur only on my machine, I reproduced it on my teammates machines and clients machines. Maybe my description is bad) The offset appears when you move mouse fast, second point of the line begins not to match current mouse position. More speed - more space between second point and current mouse position (lag). Thanks

Comment: I used `inkCanvas` for the same purpose and did not experience any problems. Maybe you can take a shot with that.

Comment: InkCanvas has the same problem. I as far As I understood this cannot be fixed because there will be always a delay because of WPF internal render system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be fixed because this is due to WPF's internal render system. There will always be a lag even if visual tree is simple. Complex visual tree results to more delay. I've spend a lot of time trying solving this.

Comment: Oh. I also met with this problem. WPF is simply not so good at fast drawing I guess..

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MouseMove` event not on main canvas but on Window itself.
I recently got same problem using `MouseMove` on `Image` and it was laggy as hell
Switching to window's event helped me a lot.

```
<Window x:Name="Window1" x:Class="WpfApp2.MViewer"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MViewer" Height="454.411" Width="730.515" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Closing="Window1_Closing" ContentRendered="Window1_ContentRendered" MouseMove="Window1_MouseMove">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="Image1" MouseMove="Image1_MouseMove"/>
        <Line Name="Line1" Visibility="Visible" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="0.75" />
        <Line Name="Line2" Visibility="Visible" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="0.75" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and

```
        private void Window1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Line1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Line1.X1 = Mouse.GetPosition(this).X;
            Line1.X2 = Mouse.GetPosition(this).X;
            Line1.Y1 = 0;
            Line1.Y2 = Window1.Height;

            Line2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Line2.X1 = 0;
            Line2.X2 = Window1.Width;
            Line2.Y1 = Mouse.GetPosition(this).Y;
            Line2.Y2 = Mouse.GetPosition(this).Y;
        }
```